# Response message is forbidden when queried for video on youtube analytics api

Tags: youtube-api

I used the **youtube analytics api** console ([https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?][1]) to retrieve details of videos (from my channel), values for **id** : channel==4aYYO.... metrics : video .
    The response I get is 403 **Forbidden**  code: 403, message: "Forbidden
    Can anyone point out if I am missing any permission ?

```
      [1]: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?
```

Comment: Are you using any of the client libraries?  Have you authorized the request with oauth?

Comment: Yes did the Oauth steps. I am not using client libraries, was trying through the explorer only. I turned on the Youtube Analytics Api and Youtube Data Api in https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:412742509277:services ..

Answer (score 0):

Channel ids begin with `UC`. Can you try `UC4aYYO...` and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

First, use the ChannelList method in the YouTube Data API to your Channel ID's. This must be an authenticated call, so click the Authorize Requests slider in the API explorer. Make sure you are logged in with the Google account which owns the channel.

API Explorer Query

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet&mine=true&_h=1&
```

Here is more explanation from Jeff at Google.

[How do I get a list of YouTube channels, and associated channel URLs (user or channel), owned by an authenticated user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16620521/2170704)