# How do I get a list of YouTube channels, and associated channel URLs (user or channel), owned by an authenticated user

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels, youtube.net-api

We use the following call to get ChannelID's for an authenticated user and it works well for most cases. Some YouTube user connect their channels to a Google+ page and this fails for one of our users in that situation. In that case, the call only returns the channelID associated the user's email account used for authentication, not all channels owned by the user.

```
System.IO.Stream resultStream = service.Query(new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%2CtopicDetails&mine=true&key=" + GlobalSettings.developerKey));
```

Also, we construct the channel URL by appending the channelID to the following URL.

```
http://www.youtube.com/channel/
```

However, some channels us a user name and path instead of channelID. How can I detect that the type is *user* instead of *channel*? In that case the user name is appending to the following path. The Google+ user's main channel uses this path with a user name.

```
http://www.youtube.com/user/
```

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

1. In v3 of the YouTube Data API, you're forced to work with channel ids everywhere. This is a good thing. Channel ids are the only universal way of identifying channels! Legacy usernames used to serve that purpose as well, but the number of channels without legacy usernames is increasing by the day, so writing new v2 code that relies on legacy usernames is not recommended (and isn't possible in v3).
2. When making a `channels.list(..., mine=true)` call, you're always going to get back exactly one channel. The channel you get back will depend on which channel was chosen when you went through the OAuth 2 flow—there's a picker within that flow that lets you choose whichever channel you'd like if your Google Account happens to have access to more than one channel. If you want to operate on a different channel, you need to explicitly obtain an OAuth 2 token for that channel.
3. `channel.list(..., managedByMe=true)` can return multiple channels, but that API call is only relevant to YouTube content partners, and is used hand-in-hand with the `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter. Most developers can safely ignore this unless you know you're explicitly working with YouTube content partners' accounts.
4. The URL to visit a channel's page isn't returned anywhere in the v3 API response—that's true, and maybe it should be (feel free to [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Enhancement%20Request%29)). If you want to manually construct the URL, you can use `http://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID`, where `CHANNEL_ID` is the standard `UC...` value that is used everywhere else in v3. That should produce a valid URL regardless of whether there's also a legacy username for the channel.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I have been able to do this is to use the v2 API, instead of v3. Specifically, you can use the same OAuth token, but access this API endpoint:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?v=2
```

It will return an XML doc that contains both a URL to the user's channel (using the channel id), as well as the YouTube username.

See https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#User_profile_entry for more info.

Comment: Thanks. That will help by providing the full url and the username. I still need to get a complete list of all channels owned by a user. Will this provide a complete list when the user's channel is linked to a Google+ account or page?

Comment: AFIK, there's a one-to-one relationship between a youtube channel and a user login. This means there will always be one item in the channel list. Unless, of course your YT account is a YT-CMS account (think NBC, or BBC). I have zero experience with YT-CMS accounts, so apologies for not being able to help out in that regard.